Error: Problem: package gdal-devel-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel requires libgdal.so.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
I have a RHEL8 machine with "8.10 (Ootpa)".
I am trying to install the following package but getting the following errors:
$ yum install gdal-devel -y


Last metadata expiration check: 2:56:33 ago on Wed 29 May 2024 06:35:50 AM EDT.
Error:
 Problem: package gdal-devel-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel requires libgdal.so.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package gdal-devel-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel requires gdal-libs(x86-64) = 3.0.4-12.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libdap.so.25()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel
  - nothing provides libdapclient.so.6()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel
  - nothing provides libdapserver.so.7()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)


When I try to --nobest or --skipbroken I still get similar errors:
$ yum install gdal-devel --nobest --skip-broken


 Problem: package gdal-devel-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel requires libgdal.so.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package gdal-devel-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel requires gdal-libs(x86-64) = 3.0.4-12.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libdap.so.25()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel
  - nothing provides libdapclient.so.6()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel
  - nothing provides libdapserver.so.7()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-12.el8.x86_64 from epel
=============================================================================================================
 Package                    Architecture           Version                        Repository            Size
=============================================================================================================
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 gdal-devel                 x86_64                 3.0.4-12.el8                   epel                 203 k
 gdal-libs                  x86_64                 3.0.4-12.el8                   epel                 7.5 M

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================
Skip  2 Packages

Nothing to do.


When I try to search for libdap alone with yum I get the following:
$ yum install libdap

No match for argument: libdap
Error: Unable to find a match: libdap

Has anyone had this issue before?

We are running into the same problem. Did you find a fix for this?

Yes, I had to subscribe to RHEL and download to packages directly from the repolist.
It might be possible to do so with what you find in Fedora repos.
